# Using crypto and stock OHLCV data together. How to handle the no-trading gaps to avoid index and indicator problems?

Tags: python, numpy, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency

Hello trading and programming experts!

I need your expertise in using stock data together with crypto data in the same strategy. I have a problem with the gaps from non-trading times.
Let's say we are on a daily timeframe (to keep its simple, would like it to work on intraday too):

```
monday = close_crypto[1]
tuesday = close_crypto[2]
wednesday = close_crypto[3]
thursday = close_crypto[4]
friday= close_crypto[5]
saturday = close_crypto[6]
sunday = close_crypto[7]
```

```
monday = close_stocks[1]
tuesday = close_stocks[2]
wednesday = close_stocks[3]
thursday = close_stocks[4]
friday= close_stocks[5]
saturday = close_stocks[6]  # not available = np.nan 
sunday = close_stocks[7]  # not available = np.nan
```

On `self.index == 6` we start having problems. We can't leave it just empty (drop the `NaN`s) because then the index wouldn't match with dates anymore. For example the `self.index == 6` would be the 17. Oct. 2020 on crypto candles and 19. Oct 2020 on stock candles.

If we set it to `np.nan` the index matches again, but calculating indicators like averages doesn't work with the array. If we set "missing" candles to the last existing candle values (= forward filling), we get different/wrong indicator values.

How do you handle that? My idea, for now, would be:

1. forward fill stock_data, but keep the old array for indicator calculations: stock_data_with_nan
2. for indicator calculations on stocks I would need a helper, that uses the stock_data_with_nan, but skips the np.nan in the calculation and then returns the indicator data forward filled.

What are your thoughts?
For the discontinuous series helper function, I also could need help from some NumPy experts.

Thought about something like that:

```
discontinuous_series_helper(lambda series: ta.sma(series, 20), close_stocks_with_NaN)
```

Thank you all in advance!